# I/O exception with user settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

I have created a **C#** project in ***Visual Studio 2012***. This project has user settings associated with it (through Project Properties).
When I open it in my projects release folder, it works exactly as expected, however when I copy it to another directory (along with the required DLLs) it fails to open. The error it returns is:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
```

Previous versions without the user settings work without problem. There are also some other changes made in this version, but I think that the user settings is the most likely culprit.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be the problem?

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

  Problem Signature 01: qpcr analysis.exe

  Problem Signature 02: 3.2.0.0

  Problem Signature 03: 50ec6ead

  Problem Signature 04: qPCR Analysis

  Problem Signature 05: 3.2.0.0

  Problem Signature 06: 50ec6ead

  Problem Signature 07: 5

  Problem Signature 08: 6

  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException

  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

  Locale ID: 4105

  Additional Information 1: 9816

  Additional Information 2: 9816eb613a03e199ce2e07ad653fd9a9

  Additional Information 3: c23a

  Additional Information 4: c23aa0fa39dc45b08efe4b182be4c6e7

Comment: That's the information from the error message, I don't seem to be able to get a stack trace.

Comment: Are you copying the resource file?

Comment: @SLaks: It works fine in VS, so the debugger's not much user here.

Comment: @glace: no, what is the resource file?

Comment: @HH: Set the debugger to launch the exe from that folder.  (in Project Properties)

Comment: @SLaks: I changed the Debug working directory under Project Properties, is that enough? It still works, so I'm guessing not.

Comment: @HH: No.  Set it to Start extenal program.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm using express, I don't think that feature's available to me.